# trying to avoid using data classes with copy method to assign a new object

Tags: kotlin

I have the following data class

```
data class Passport(
    val byr: String = "",
    val iyr: String = "",
    val eyr: String = "",
    val hgt: String = "",
    val hcl: String = "",
    val ecl: String = "",
    val pid: String = "",
    val cid: String = ""
)
```

And I have this enum class

```
enum class PassportFields(val field: String) {
    BYR("byr"),
    IYR("iyr"),
    EYR("eyr"),
    HGT("hgt"),
    HCL("hcl"),
    ECL("ecl"),
    PID("pid"),
    CID("cid")
}
```

I have this method that will create the individual passports but I have to use a when statement.

What I would like to avoid is having the mutable `passportData` I would really like to have something like this `val passportData = ....` However, if I would do something like that I can't assign using the `.copy(...)`

I would also like to avoid using the copy to assign a new object each time.

`passportData = passportData.copy(byr = field)`

This is my method

```
fun List<String>.parsePassports(): List<Passport> {
    return this.map { passportField ->
        val passport = passportField.split("\n", " ")
        
        var passportData = Passport()

        passport.map { field ->
            when(field) {
                PassportFields.BYR.field -> {
                    passportData = passportData.copy(byr = field)
                }
                PassportFields.IYR.field -> {
                    passportData = passportData.copy(iyr = field)
                }
                PassportFields.EYR.field -> {
                    passportData = passportData.copy(eyr = field)
                }
                PassportFields.HGT.field -> {
                    passportData = passportData.copy(hgt = field)
                }
                PassportFields.HCL.field -> {
                    passportData = passportData.copy(hcl = field)
                }
                PassportFields.ECL.field -> {
                    passportData = passportData.copy(ecl = field)
                }
                PassportFields.PID.field -> {
                    passportData = passportData.copy(pid = field)
                }
                PassportFields.CID.field -> {
                    passportData = passportData.copy(cid = field)
                }
            }
        }
        passportData
    }
}
```

=== UPDATE ===

```
fun List<String>.parsePassportsV3(): List<Passport> {
    return map { passportField ->
        val listOfPassport = passportField.split("\n", " ").associateBy { it.substringBefore(":") }
            .mapValues {
                it.value.substringAfter(":")
            }

        Passport(
            byr = listOfPassport.getOrDefault(PassportFields.BYR.field, ""),
            iyr = listOfPassport.getOrDefault(PassportFields.IYR.field, ""),
            eyr = listOfPassport.getOrDefault(PassportFields.EYR.field, ""),
            hgt = listOfPassport.getOrDefault(PassportFields.HGT.field, ""),
            hcl = listOfPassport.getOrDefault(PassportFields.HCL.field, ""),
            ecl = listOfPassport.getOrDefault(PassportFields.ECL.field, ""),
            pid = listOfPassport.getOrDefault(PassportFields.PID.field, ""),
            cid = listOfPassport.getOrDefault(PassportFields.CID.field, ""),
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered making each field of the `Passport` class a `var` instead of `val`?

Comment: I would like to keep every field of the class to be `immutable` using `val` Once the class is created I don't want the fields to be modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fun List<String>.parsePassportsV3(): List<Passport> {
    return map { passportField ->
        val listOfPassport = passportField.split("\n", " ").associateBy { it.substringBefore(":") }
            .mapValues {
                it.value.substringAfter(":")
            }

        Passport(
            byr = listOfPassport.getOrDefault(PassportFields.BYR.field, ""),
            iyr = listOfPassport.getOrDefault(PassportFields.IYR.field, ""),
            eyr = listOfPassport.getOrDefault(PassportFields.EYR.field, ""),
            hgt = listOfPassport.getOrDefault(PassportFields.HGT.field, ""),
            hcl = listOfPassport.getOrDefault(PassportFields.HCL.field, ""),
            ecl = listOfPassport.getOrDefault(PassportFields.ECL.field, ""),
            pid = listOfPassport.getOrDefault(PassportFields.PID.field, ""),
            cid = listOfPassport.getOrDefault(PassportFields.CID.field, ""),
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to create any extra objects, but also want the `Passport` properties to be `val`s. This means that you must get all the values for the fields ready, before you call the constructor for `Passport`. You can't create a half-created passport, and then gradually assign things to it as you loop over the list `passport`.

Luckily, the value for each passport field `f` can be easily computed: if the list `passport` contains `f`, then the value is `f`, otherwise it is `""`.

Hence:

```
fun List<String>.parsePassports(): List<Passport> {
    return this.map { passportField ->
        val passport = passportField.split("\n", " ").toSet()
        Passport(
            PassportFields.BYR.field.takeIf(passport::contains) ?: "",
            PassportFields.IYR.field.takeIf(passport::contains) ?: "",
            PassportFields.EYR.field.takeIf(passport::contains) ?: "",
            PassportFields.HGT.field.takeIf(passport::contains) ?: "",
            PassportFields.HCL.field.takeIf(passport::contains) ?: "",
            PassportFields.ECL.field.takeIf(passport::contains) ?: "",
            PassportFields.PID.field.takeIf(passport::contains) ?: "",
            PassportFields.CID.field.takeIf(passport::contains) ?: "",
        )
    }
}
```

You *could* put this in a loop, but I actually find this less readable:

```
val arguments = PassportFields.values().map { 
    it.field.takeIf(passport::contains) ?: ""
}
Passport(
    arguments[0],
    arguments[1],
    arguments[2],
    arguments[3],
    arguments[4],
    arguments[5],
    arguments[6],
    arguments[7],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data class Passport(
  val byr: String = "",
  val iyr: String = "",
  val eyr: String = "",
  val hgt: String = "",
  val hcl: String = "",
  val ecl: String = "",
  val pid: String = "",
  val cid: String = ""
)

fun List<String>.parsePassports(): List<Passport> {
  return this.map { passportString ->
    val parts = passportString
      .split("\n", ":")
      .chunked(2)
      .groupBy { it.first() }
      .mapValues { (_, value) -> value[0][1] }
    Passport(
      byr = parts["byr"]?: "",
      iyr = parts["iyr"]?: "",
      eyr = parts["eyr"]?: "",
      hgt = parts["hgt"]?: "",
      hcl = parts["hcl"]?: "",
      ecl = parts["ecl"]?: "",
      pid = parts["pid"]?: "",
      cid = parts["cid"]?: ""
    )
  }
}

val data = listOf(
  "byr:2001\niyr:2019\neyr:2029\nhgt:185\nhcl:#cfa07d\necl:blu\npid:000123456\ncid:147",
  "byr:1965\niyr:2015\neyr:2025\nhgt:177\nhcl:#afb90b\necl:amb\npid:123456789\ncid:78",
)

val result = data.parsePassports()

println(result)
```

Comment: I updated my answer that is very smiliar to yours. Instead I used `associateBy` and  `mapValues`